# Is it safe to connect buck feedback after current sense shunt resistor?

Tags: buck, current-measurement, feedback

Is it safe to connect feedback voltage divider to output voltage after current sense amplifier instead of connecting it before current sense resistor? Will this connection influence regulator stability or accuracy? I want to do this for compensating CSA resistor voltage drop.

[image: Feedback divider sourced by voltage after current sense resistor]

Comment: might move it even further down, right on the output connector if possible to compensate for copper losses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is it safe to connect feedback voltage divider to output voltage after
> current sense amplifier instead of connecting it before current sense
> resistor?*

Yes, it's usually safe and reliable providing R15 is quite low compared to the load on REG_OUT.

> *Will this connection influence regulator stability or accuracy?*

It improves the accuracy at REG_OUT and, under certain circumstances, it can reduce stability but, keep R15 low in value compared to the load.

> *I want to do this for compensating CSA resistor voltage drop.*

Yes, I understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Your C20 decoupling capacitor should also be after R15 (on the right-hand side). R15 will have negligible effect on stability (it just appears as slight winding resistance of the coil).